# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to validate mobile line using Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am implementing Fluent Validation to Validate mobile line using PhoneNumber as shown below:

```
public static IRuleBuilder<T, string> PhoneNumber<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
{
    var options = ruleBuilder
        .Matches(@"^\([0-9]{3})?\)$")
        .WithMessage("Mobile number format should be 234xxxxxxxxxxx");
    return options;
}
```

Then I called it in:

```
public class AdminCreateDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<AdminCreateDto>
{
    public AdminCreateDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(user => user.MobileNumber).PhoneNumber()
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Mobile Number cannot be null")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Mobile Number field is required. ERROR!");
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

```
Invalid pattern '^\([0-9]{3})?\)$' at offset 12. Too many )'s.
```

How do I fix it and also achieve my goal for 234xxxxxxxxxxx, and should be maximum of 13 digits

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern for making it work:

```cs
...
 .Matches(@"^\+?[0-9]{3,13}$")
...
```

you can change the min (3) and max (13) length.

if you want the mobile number start with 234 then you do this:

```cs
...
 .Matches(@"^234\+?[0-9]{0,13}$")
...
```